# Php - What does this code mean?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code

```
$arr =  array(
     'media[]'  => "@{$image};type=image/jpeg;filename={$image}"
);
```

I do not know what line 2 means. 
What do the `[]`, `@` and `{}` stand for?

**UPDATE:**

This is a code extracted from [*Upload images on Twitter using PHP*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873217/1137788).

Used to upload images to Twitter. I need to implement the same in Lua. Hence this question.

Comment: The code has syntax error, missed `'`.

Comment: Seems like an output for a template engine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr =  array(
     'media[]'  => "@{$image};type=image/jpeg;filename={$image}",
);
```

is just like

```
$arr =  array(
     'media[]'  => "@".$image.";type=image/jpeg;filename=".$image,
);
```

See [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) for what the curly brackets (`{}`) mean in double-quoted strings.

And for `"[]"` and `"@"` they are just normal strings.

Comment: Oh?  I thought the `@` has some significance in Lua like in Objective-c.  Is the `@` just part of the string then?

Comment: @SatheeshJM Just normal strings in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Something error in this code.This is set a output path of the image..is this a Template code ?

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.